# List-type explanation

Tags: java, variables

Perhaps a bit misleading title, but not sure how to word it.

In the example of an ArrayList, what are the differences between these two list-objects:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
```

Note: I know about the list hierarchy, interfaces and inheritance, but I am not sure how it applies in this situation. Can anyone please help me clear this up?

Comment: Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936556/when-you-make-an-arraylist-without-specifying-the-object-type-does-it-create-it

Comment: *I know about the list hierarchy, interfaces and inheritance, but I am not sure how it applies in this situation.* It doesn't apply in this case because your not using any of that. It's about raw/parameterised type. The type-safety is off in the 1st and on in the 2nd.

Comment: Well, considering I am able to do create an ArrayList instance without any type-assignment on either the left or right side, what is the purpose of the right-hand <Integer>-specification?

Comment: The <Integer> specification indicates what the expected type is that the list will hold. This will allow for compile time checks to ensure you are only putting integers into the list and not a mix of types. This helps reduce errors.

Comment: Does the second even compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

will give a warning about using the raw ArrayList object since you are not specifing the list is of a generic ArrayList type.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
```

will give an unchecked conversion warning since you are assigning a non-generic ArrayList to a typed ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

will work in java7+. The diamond operator tells the compiler to infer the generic type.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

is the standard way of using an ArrayList even it is more long winded than the new java7 syntax.

Comment: Minor quibble -- the diamond operator was introduced in Java 7